# Alternate to taglist in vim

Tags: vim, ctags, taglist

I've been using ctags+taglist for a while, trying to build up an IDE for myself.
Taglist does do a great job, but it occasionally crashes when cooperating with buffers in my vim.
As a newcomer, I see there may be some issues with my way of using the plugin, but I cannot find them. Also, the code of Taglist is far too complex for me to understand or modify.
So my question is: Is there an [simple] alternate to the Taglist plugin?
Documents about the implementation of Taglist are also welcomed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at [Tagbar](http://majutsushi.github.com/tagbar/) and [winmanager](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1440). Taglist is ready to use with winmanager.